# Android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone

I am creating an android application for the first time and learning.

When I updated something to a website, could those updated one reflected on the android automatically?

And another question is, are Android and iPhone related? or they have their own software to design individually?

Thanks, your responds are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question you would need a webservice of some sort to provide this data to your app.

This can be done using PHP, C# or any other webtechnique.

You would than have to parse the JSON or XML on the client side (in the app).

This is the basic Server-Client structure that most apps use.